# Forward proxying TCP connections in Nodejs with thousands of different proxy IPs?

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp, haproxy, squid

I have a use case where users of my SaaS need outbound connections from my servers to come from a custom IP corresponding to that user. I'm struggling to come up with a way to do this.

In this example there are 3 users, 1 server, and 3 custom IPs denoted as 0.0.0.0 just as an example. Each customer's outbound requests must come from their IP but the processing is done on a single server:

```
User 1 requests --> server 1 --> outbound data to different destination in new TCP request coming from 0.0.0.1
User 2 requests --> server 1 --> outbound data to different destination in new TCP request coming from 0.0.0.2
User 3 requests --> server 1 --> outbound data to different destination in new TCP request coming from 0.0.0.3
```

My theoretical idea of how to manage this is to have a server for each customer configured as a forward proxy, such as HAproxy or Squid. Then when requests come into my Nodejs app it selects the proxy corresponding to that user and proxies the request through it.

Does this sound right or is there is much better way to do this that I am missing?

EDIT:
This question is only interested in forward proxies. A reverse proxy is not within the scope of this question.

Comment: IANA has reserved three IPv4 address ranges for examples (`192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`), and you should use those rather than an invalid range. There is also an (large) IPv6 range for this (`2001:db8::/32`) that can be subnetted into billions of standard `/64` networks.

Comment: Your server would be creating a new TCP connection because the outbound from the server is a different address (a TCP connect simply cannot change the original source or destination IP or TCP addresses without breaking the connection). This may not work if the client is behind NAT or a firewall because connection requests inbound to the client would be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Comments: When you want to connet from one server to customers this in effect can then only mean http outbound requests/connections. So if you need an HTTP library like this one: https://github.com/request/request and set the

```
localAddress - local interface to bind for network connections.
```

parameter according to your source ip. so in effect you are connecting from your single server to an arbitray IP of your customer.

```
Customer 1 => Loadbalancer => Server 1 (sends ok response) => Server 1 starts a new onnection to the customer with 0.0.0.1.
```

Important however is, that you do the response (with the customer specifc IP) on the Host where you loadbalancer is. You can only send requests from an IP, if that host has this IP assigned.

```
Cust1        LB      
       +---> IPs    +---> server
Cust2        0.0.0.1     1.1.1.1   1.Connection from User. Server stores the request and answeres with 200 OK Status. 
^            0.0.0.2        +      2.Server does processing
|            ....           |
|                           |      3.Server has completed processing and sends response to customer
|          +----------+     |      by connecting to your own proxy with the paylod  to send to the customer. the payload must contain the ip it should send the data to, as well as the "real/actutal" data. Or you can pass the ip in custom http headers.
           |Listening:|     |
+--------+ |2.2.2.2   |<----+
           |out:      |
           |0.0.0.1   |
           |0.0.0.2   |
           |...       |
           +----------+
                4. Your proxy does an outgoing connection to the customer and sends your data/paylod it received. 

            Your proxy:
            1. Needs to be running on your LB-Host (to share the IPS)
            2. Listing on arbitrary port and IP like http://2.2.2.2:8811/rest/connecttocustomer (but not on the ones already taken by LB)
            3. Your proxy uses an HTTP Library and connects to your customer http.request(dest=4.4.4.4, source=0.0.0.1, "send  this data")
            4. Your proxy is a simple nodejs App that has an arbitrary API (see 2.) and then does the outgoing request to the customer (see 3.). 
            You can implement it as a dump proxy that only listens on an api from incoming requests from your server and then connects (with a new(!) request) to your customer (as above). But you can also implement it more complex as some kind of queue/async system and outbound notifcation system (so it might contain more logic).
```

Comment: I was not clear in what I was asking for. These are not the same TCP connections, they are new connections to different destinations. Think of the customer's request as queuing an item to be executed, then the execution starts a new TCP connection to a different host. I don't understand the rest of your response. I cannot simply assign thousands of IPs to a single server. Plus the pool of IPs I need to use need to be usable by all servers I have accepting customer data.

Comment: Ok responding to your edit: I already have a reverse proxy and it is not in the scope of this question. My question is regarding how to handle a forward proxy from a pool of servers.

Comment: @sonrh: I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is not relevant to my question, there is no such thing as a forward load balancer, I'm not sure why you called it that.

Comment: @sonrh, I changed the wordings from LB to proxy. Yes proxy might be a better term. But in effect you can call it whaterver you want Loadblancer, Outbound-Messaging System, Proxy. In effect they all do roughly the same. They listen for jobs from your server and then execute the outgoing request (with the payload)

Comment: @sonrh, something like that you need to implement (on your Host with your LB). https://www.vanamco.com/2014/06/24/proxy-requests-in-node-js/ But note, i have not read this article. But the principle is. Your Proxy listens for requests from your server . Reads all data in Memory. Then establishes an outgoing connection to your customer with this data.

Comment: I wonder if Linux and Node supports thousands of IPs registered as proxies and selecting them on a case by case basis. Another option I thought of was to write my own TCP forwarder in Node. Basically my processing server would send a request to my TCP forwarder which would then technically make the real request.

Comment: @sonrh: I do not see any problems with Linux or Node handling thousands of IPs per host. But the real problem is IPV4 Addresses are not cheap. AWS charges per IP about 3.5 USD per Month! 
Furthermore having that many IP means lots of traffic/bandwith. Most likely you need to split traffic to severl nodes (Proxies/TCP forwarder) because of this. 
Thirdly, using IP per Customer is rather an Anti-Pattern, this makes it impossible to do failover in case of errors. I would avoid such "Hard binding" wherever possible and work with a dynamic mapping (use dns/domain names).

Comment: I appreciate the answer Markus. Unfortunately each customer has to have a dedicated IP in my use case (email reputation) and I charge plenty to cover the few dollars for the IP. Do you have any actual examples of doing the proxying in Node? Searching for the word proxy on the net documentation comes up with nothing :(

Comment: I just had a chance to read through your article you posted. While it talks about HTTP I think I can adapt his examples to TCP.